# how to embed a stream from a 147 address but it takes images

Tags: video, stream, embed

We have this feed: http://147.126.8.47/appletvid.html and I need to embed this stream into a blog, just the images getting updated. Does anyone know how to does this? I tried a few regular embed codes but it not working. The images are updating every second so not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The full image is here: http://147.126.8.47/now.jpg, and would be easy to embed in a page. (Click the link and keep refreshing to see how it works. Notice the timestamp at the bottom left.)

The bad news is that the link you sent includes a page that automatically reloads the image -- so to get it to animate on the page you're embedding to, you'll want to write some Javascript to keep updating the image in place.

Comment: and it doesn't seem to be a nice way to refresh the image fast as it's not very small and can have negative impact both on server's and visitor's network resources, and add some processing overhead to the client's browser and CPU possibly.